Drawing a text node in TikZ?
I'm looking for some assistance in improving a useful (I think) function in TikZ.
Drawing a rectangle in TikZ is easy
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,5);

I have always thought it would be handy if the same sort of code could be used for a node with text:
\dnode (0,0) (4,5) {Some possibly useful text.};

My ideal (so far unachieved) might be something like this:
\draw (0,0) text (4,5) {Some possibly useful text.};

Done using \node, this might look something like:
\node[text width=4cm,minimum height=5cm,anchor=north west] at (0,0) {Some possibly useful text.};

The \dnode (for dnode) macro I am suggesting would use the coordinates to calculate the text width and     minimum height of the node and place it appropriately.
The macros I suggest accomplish this, but certainly can be improved, likely using some inner TikZ facilities of which I am unaware. Suggestions are most welcome...
The principle is simple: A rectangle is drawn given UL and LR, and a node of the same size as the rectangle (inner sep set to 0pt) is placed at the center of the rectangle. An option is available to use a \parbox (#7=*) in the node that allows for the equivalent of inner sep appear to be used.
There are two definitions of \dnode shown: The first uses the \path let... construction to arrive at the necessary dimensions; the second uses brute force to calculate the dimensions. Both produce identically the same output.
Elementary diagnostics are available using \diagnosetrue: this prints the number of the node (as a node label) and draws the outline of the node itself.
A problem solved, sort of
It would seem that no combination of transform shape and shape border rotate seems to rotate the border of a rectangular node. Or, far more likely, I am missing something. See text box 5 (use \diagnosetrue). To overcome this, there is rotatenode={<either ±90 or ±180>}. Note that this rotates the node's contents and its anchors. My current solution for this seems cumbersome, so some suggestions would be welcome.
I am quite sure that I have overlooked some basics, and that the code could should be improved, so comments are welcome. On the whole, I am pleasantly surprised by the brevity (and therefore manageability) of the code.
Details of the \dnode macro, which attempts to replicate TikZ usage:
The macro \dnode (both versions) takes the same 8 (?!?, testing the limits) arguments:
#1 * flag that uses \path instead of \draw, i.e., no rectangle drawn
#2 [Options to the node]
#3 UL (or UR, starting) coordinate, either (<dim>,<dim>) or (<named>)
#4 + a flag to add box incrementally
#5 LR (or LL, ending) coordinate, either (<dim>,<dim>) or (<named>)
#6 {Node text}
#7 * flag, use \parbox to allow more flexibility in formatting and appearance of inner sep
#8 [Options to TikZ rectangle]
\documentclass[tikz,border=6pt]{standalone}% Uses \path let... approach

\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds}% backgrounds used just for demonstration

\newcounter{nodenum}% naming and diagnostics
\newif\ifdiagnose

%% |=====8><-----| %%

\tikzset{%
    diagnostics/.code={\ifdiagnose \tikzset{draw,label={[inner sep=0pt,text=purple,
        anchor=north,font=\tiny]\thenodenum},label distance=0pt}\fi},
    dnode/.style={align=center,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text width=\mywd,
        minimum height=\myht,alias=N-\thenodenum,diagnostics
    },
    rotatenode/.code={% there *has* to be a better way
        \ifnum\fpeval{abs(#1)}=90
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\myparwd}{\myht}%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\myparht}{\mywd}%
            \tikzset{rotate=#1,text width=\myht,minimum height=\mywd}%
        \else
            \tikzset{rotate=#1}%
        \fi
    }% rotates a node and its anchors. Only sensible values are ±90 and ±180
}

%%%% Use either this:
% \path let... construction: #1* \draw/\path; #2 node opts.; #3 point 1; #4+ increment?;
% #5 point 2; #6 node text; #7* use \parbox; #8 rectangle opts.
\NewDocumentCommand{\dnode}{s O{} r() t+ r() m s O{}}{% mimics tikz code; needs <;>
    \stepcounter{nodenum}
    \coordinate (UL) at (#3);
    \IfBooleanTF{#4}% is incremental?
        {\coordinate (LR) at (#5);\coordinate (LLR) at ($(#3)+(#5)$);}% yes
        {\coordinate (LR) at ($(#3)-(#5)$);\coordinate (LLR) at (#5);}% no
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\path}{\draw}[#8] let \p1=(LR) in % use \draw or \path?
        \pgfextra{%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\mywd}{abs(\x1)}% \x1 = text box width
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\myht}{abs(\y1)}% \y1 = text box height
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\myparht}{\myht}% text box height
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\myparwd}{\mywd}% text box height
        }%
        (UL) rectangle node[dnode,#2]
            {% node content
                \IfBooleanTF{#7}% use parbox?
                    {\parbox[\dimexpr\myparht-6pt\relax]{\dimexpr\myparwd-6pt\relax}{#6}}% yes
                    {#6}% no
            } (LLR)
}

%%%% Or this:
% brute force construction: #1* \draw/\path; #2 node opts.; #3 point 1; #4+ increment?;
% #5 point 2; #6 node text; #7* use \parbox; #8 rectangle opts.
% \makeatletter
% \NewDocumentCommand{\dnode}{s O{} r() t+ r() m s O{}}{% mimics tikz code; needs <;>
%   \stepcounter{nodenum}% reset to 0 if necessary if in new \tikz or tikzpicture
%   \coordinate (UL) at (#3);% uuper left coord.
%   \IfBooleanTF{#4}% incremental or simple?
%       {\coordinate (LR) at ($(#3) + (#5)$);}% lower right coord for incremental text box
%       {\coordinate (LR) at (#5);}% lower right coord for simple text box
%       \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone($(UL)-(UL |- LR)$)\relax  
%       \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\myht}{abs(veclen(\the\pgf@x,\the\pgf@y))}% text box height
%       \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone($(UL)-(UL -| LR)$)\relax
%       \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\mywd}{abs(veclen(\the\pgf@x,\the\pgf@y))}% text box width
%       \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\myparht}{\myht}% text box height
%       \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\myparwd}{\mywd}% text box height
%       \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\path}{\draw}[#8] (UL) rectangle node[dnode,#2]
%           {%node contents
%               \IfBooleanTF{#7}% Use parbox or straight node? change `6pt` to suit
%                   {\parbox[\dimexpr\myparht-6pt\relax]{\dimexpr\myparwd-6pt\relax}{#6}}%
%                   {#6}%
%           } (LR)
% }
% \makeatother

\begin{document}

\diagnosefalse

\tikz[]{% Examples:
    \dnode[name=XX](0,0)(2in,1in){Huh?};% simple

    \dnode[name=yy](XX.south east)+(1.75in,-1in){More?}[fill=blue!10];% increment

    \dnode[name=zz,font=\itshape](yy.south west)+(-1.5in,-1in){Really? This is a bunch of bla bla bla to see what happens in this particular case.}*;% increment

    \dnode[name=qq](zz.north west)+(-0.5in,0.5in){Wow};% increment

    \dnode[name=ww,font=\scriptsize,rotatenode={90}]($(qq.south west) - (0.5in,0.25in)$) + (0.5in,-1.5in){Some text in a narrow column this is long.};

    %% the node shape needs to be rotated as well... how? <shape border rotate> does no work
    \dnode[red,name=ww,rotatenode={-90}]([xshift=-0.275in]zz.north)+(0.55in,0.75in)
        {\tiny One\\Two\\Three\\};% increment from a node coordinate; xshift=0.55in/2; note *

    \dnode (XX.north east) +(1.5in,0.25in){??}[fill=red!10];% increment with rectangle fill

    \dnode ([yshift=-0.125in]XX.east) +(2in,0.25in){!!};% increment from node coordinate

    \dnode ([yshift=0.125in]XX.west) +(-0.75in,-0.25in){**};% increment from node coordinate

    \dnode[name=tt,rotatenode={90}] ($(yy.south west) + (0.5in,-0.5in)$) +(1in,-1.5in)
        {interesting};% increment from displaced node coordinate

    \dnode[name=qq] ([xshift=-0.5in]zz.south) +(1in,-0.5in) {?!?};% increment from node coordinate

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]% filled rectangle obscures adjacent rules if in front
        \dnode* (zz.north east) (tt.north east) {\centering Yikes.}*[fill=orange!10];% simple between two node coordinates; note *
    \end{scope}
    
    \dnode (0.5in,1.5in) (0,1.25in)  {$\pi$};% #3 first=UR, #5 second=LL
}%

\end{document}



Just wondering: what is your question? Or do you want to present a solution?

My question is "I am quite sure that I have overlooked some basics, and that the code could should be improved, so comments are welcome." This cannot be the only, or even the best, way to accomplish this. Suggestions?

I seggest to edit your question and put your question more explicitely close to or at the beginning. Thank you // Why don't you just use anchors, e.g. in polar notation?

@MS-SPO Good  point. Done. Could you flesh-out your suggestion?

This demonstrates most of what's needed to replicate your example, i.e. there's nothing new needed to replicate the parts I left out:

position nodes first, using names and anchor points
introduce required node-styles step by step
use a little x- or yshift here and there

The slight mismatch in outer frames can be compensated by suitable settings.
If you want to use a kind of grid, you'd introduce that mainly via minimum width and height in the styles.

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

% ~~~ shorthand notation ~~~~~~~~~~~
\def\real{Really? This is a \\bunch of bla bla bla to\\see what \dots}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    bx/.style={draw,align=center,minimum width=15mm},
    hu/.style={bx,minimum width=5cm,minimum height=2cm},
    co/.style={bx,minimum width=3cm},
    qm/.style={bx,minimum width=2cm,fill=orange!20!red!20},
    mo/.style={bx,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=2cm,fill=blue!20},
    re/.style={bx,align=left,font=\it,minimum height=2cm},
    ot/.style={bx,text=red,rotate=-90},
 ]
    % ~~~ huh? - related ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[hu]                   (HU) at (0,0)                       {Huh?};
    \node[co,anchor=west]       (CO) at (HU.east)                   {!!}; 
    \node[qm,anchor=south west] (QM) at (HU.north east)             {??}; 
    \node[bx,anchor=east]       (AS) at (HU.west)                   {**}; 
    \node[bx,anchor=south west] (PI) at ([yshift=1cm]HU.north west) {$\pi$}; 
    \node[mo,anchor=north west] (MO) at (HU.south east)             {More?}; 

    % ~~~ more? - related ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[re,anchor=north east] (RE) at (MO.south west)             {\real}; 

    % ~~~ really? - related ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[ot,anchor=east]       (OT)at (RE.north)           {One\\Two\\Three};
    
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

